# How to encapsulate code in SharePoint 2010 and make it accessible across multiple solutions

Tags: development, maintenance

Anyone know the best way to reference functions in a solution to be used for any/all other solutions (web parts, application pages, timer jobs, etc)?

I have several small modules of code that I've copied to multiple solutions that I'd prefer to maintain in one solution that can be called from other solutions.

I don't know the best way to do this.

**Please provide step-by-step instructions or a link that has that.**

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

What I've discovered so far...

Option 1: I found instructions on how to [Creating a Custom ASP.NET (ASMX) Web Service in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msmvps.com/windsor/2011/11/04/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-asp-net-asmx-web-service-in-sharepoint-2010/), but I've been told that's not the most efficient way to reference functions in another solution and that there's a performance hit for that.

Option 2: I also found instructions on [Working with Assemblies in the GAC](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-09-19/working-with-assemblies-in-the-global-assembly-cache), but I don't know if that's the most efficient way to do this either.

I know Option 1 works. I've tried it. **I like this option because I ONLY have to redeploy the web service after making updates to it, NOT the calling solutions.** I just don't think it's the most efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a class library project and add that project as references to other solutions.

Now you just need to change/add the common project in a single place.

Another option is to have a single visual studio solution which has multiple SharePoint projects. Also add the class library project into the same solution. This way you need to only open on Visual Studio instance.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 doesn't have a class library project sir. My code uses SharePoint libraries. The only class library project i see is under Windows. Would that work? Do you have references? Link to show how to?

Comment: Yes. It will produce a DLL, which you can refer in your SharePoint projects.

Comment: If I update the code in the class library, will I need to re-deploy all of my solutions? I'm guessing yes, which would uber suck!

Comment: How is that any different from any other 3rd party DLL or Javascript library like jQuery? If they update the code and you upgrade to it, there is the potential your code breaks as a result. You need to think about breaking changes and things like that in your library or introduce methods with different signatures so you don't break your other projects.

Comment: Maybe this isn't the best way to go about doing it then. Would a deployed web service that can be called from other solutions work better? Is that even possible?

Comment: If you update your class library, you only need to update your solutions IF you have changed the signature of the interfaces or methods they use in the class library. e.g. if your "Common.dll" class library has a Log(string msg) method used by all your solutions, and you decide to update it to Log(string, boolean), you will need to update all solutions. The way to deal with that is to version your common library and have multiple versions side by side..

Answer (score 0):

I do what Amal has mentioned above.  I have a SharePoint solution called common which has my common class library project as as a reference and is also setup as an additional assembly under the advanced tab of the package.

So if I update the common code I ONLY need to deploy the common solution, all of the other solutions will automatically use the new code after the common solution is deployed without having to deploy all of the other solutions.

EDIT:

Here are some links to help you get around in visual studio regarding solutions, projects and managed references:

- [Solutions and Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Managing Project References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx)
- [How to: Create and Remove Project Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: How are you referencing "common" in your other solutions? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: It's in it's own project, so in my other solution I add the project to the solution and then add that project as a reference.  I'm not trying to be rude but this is like coding in visual studio 101.

Comment: I've added some links to my answer that should help you out in visual studio.

Comment: Steve...it's fine. I can be an absolute ass sometimes...trust me. So...how is your suggested method in any way better than putting all of my modules in a web service? If I needed to update what those modules return, I'd only have to redeploy the web service. Is one way better than the other?

Comment: i assume you are calling the webservice server side, if so, then there will be a performance penalty because of the remote call.

Comment: I'm using a web reference in the calling solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22117/discussion-between-jpollar-and-steve-lineberry).

Comment: I added some more links that show different types of references. I just don't know how you're doing it exactly. Are you referencing the GAC?

Comment: common DLL or web service, if you update the signature of the code you are using in them you'll need to update anything that calls it. Still, this is the recommended approach to modularize / isolate common code and increase reuse. Your common library needs to be stable and well-planned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a custom library into a sharepoint project, you have to add the reference into the package.package, click on the Advanced tab and add your Existing assembly.
After that add the reference to the solution, and deploy

greetings

Comment: Marco...thanks...but I'm going to need someone to send me step by step instructions. I don't even think I'm creating the class library and deploying it correctly. Even a simple "hello world" would be good at this point.

Comment: creating an example, just give me some time :p

Answer (score 0):

You have to answer two main question here:

1. How frequently you plan to modify Common part?
2. Will it be shared with other(ppbly remote) developers?

What we do in our development (example):

1. CommonProject
2. BusinessProject1
3. BusinessProject2
4. BusinessProject3

Each BusinessProject[i] a single solution that includes CommonProject.dll (cause business projects development speed can vary and we don't wanna support new features in old releases - so not project reference but rather external library reference.

CommonProject is based on an "Empty SP farm solution" project template, cause we not only have common server-side code, but also client-side (javascript), resources (14 hive images, resx-files, css, ...). It also include some 3d-party dependency assemblies that we wanna put in GAC.

Comment: 1. Hardly ever
2. No

I know how to reference 3rd party DLLs. I do it all the time. What I don't know how to do is create my own and reference them. I can never seem to be able to call the functions in a DLL that I create.

Comment: When you try, what exceptions do you see?

Comment: None. I'm not able to reference the classes at all. I don't bother building knowing that it can't see the variables or functions I'm trying to reference.

Comment: This is why I asked for step-by-step instructions. I don't know what F I'm doing.